# cast type error from long to decimal type object

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I having the following code and member value is type object and in this process = long and i want to cast it to big decimal ,when i trying the following code i get error:java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [C

```
} else if  (typeName.equals("java.math.BigDecimal"))) {
        return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal((char[]) memberValue));
```

Comment: What is the type of `memberValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message:

```
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [C
```

tells you that this cast is illegal:

```
(char[]) memberValue
```

so don't do it. The error message tells you that `memberValue` is a `Double`, so this should work:

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal((Double) memberValue));
```

Depending on the declared type of `memberValue` the cast may be completely unnecessary, though it *sounds* like the declared type is `Object`. Alternately, since there is a `BigDecimal` constructor which accepts strings, you could try to get away with this, though it's not really any less-smelly:

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(memberValue.toString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[C` represents the type "array of `char`", and indeed, you can't cast a `Double` to an array of `char`, nor should you want to. According to the message, `memberValue` is a `Double`, so you just want to do

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(memberValue));
```

Comment: thanks but when i try your proposal i getting the following DT error The constructor BigDecimal(Object) is undefined,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that error, it means that memberValue is a Double.  In this case, you should probably just use

```
new BigDecimal(memberValue)
```

but I'd have to see more code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `memberValue` is a `java.lang.Double` object, and you are trying to cast it to `char[]`. That doesn't work, because a `Double` is not a `char[]`.

In this case, you can just remove the cast, and call `doubleValue()` on the `Double` object:

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(memberValue.doubleValue()));
```

This way, you're using the constructor of `BigDecimal` that takes a `double` instead of a `char[]`.

If the type of `memberValue` is `Object`, you'll have to cast it to `Double` first:

```
((Double)memberValue).doubleValue()
```